# Speed up static website update on AWS S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website hosted on AWS S3 and Cloudfront. The first time I upload a new page, the page is available instantaneously. Then if I modify the file, changes to the website are delayed by around 24 hours.

How can I speed up this update?

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is using S3 Static website hosting.
We believe you are using CloudFront to speed up S3.

By default, when you create a CloudFront deployment, the default TTL is one day.
***If the TTL value remains, the file will not be updated.***

If your files are frequently updated, we recommend modifying the TTL.

[Modifying TTL Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnXP4.png)

We will send you a link to TTL.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

If the file is not updated frequently, but you want to update it occasionally, you can use a feature called Invalidation.
Invalidation is a function that removes the remaining TTL value.

**/images/image1.jpg

/images/image*

/images/***

You can use it in these ways.

If you have any questions, please feel free to reply!
Thank you.

Comment: In addition, I will provide a link to Invalidation.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: Invalidating did not work for the root page (mywebsite.com), I did not know what to write, but modifying TTL worked